# unable to retrieve Unicode data correctly from GUI

Tags: java, swing, unicode, character-encoding

I am sending out unicode messages from pc to phone using jsms api. When I use this part of the code, it works perfectly. I get the message displaying "ఈ ఒక తెలుగు సందేశం" perfectly.

```
    SmsMessage msg = new SmsMessage();      
    msg.setRecipient("+919561356345");   

    String unicodeMsg = "ఈ ఒక తెలుగు సందేశం";   //telugu script   

    msg.setUserData(unicodeMsg.getBytes("UTF-16BE"));
    msg.setCodingGroup(SmsMessage.DC_GROUP_GENERAL);      
    msg.setAlphabet(SmsMessage.DC_UCS2);        
    msg.setMessageClass(SmsMessage.NO_CLASS);

      service.init(props);
      service.connect();
      service.sendMessage(msg);
      System.out.println("Message sent successfuly,  "+msg.getMessage());           
      service.disconnect();
```

Now in the code, if i retrieve the same Message content from my database to swing TextArea and then extract it here, I receive a blank message on my phone. Is there some problem with the conversion and all?  This is my code:

```
// here the argument text is taMessage.getText() where taMessage is TextArea;    
public SendUnicodeMessage(String port, String text, Object no){

    SmsMessage msg = new SmsMessage();
           String num = no.toString();
           msg.setRecipient(num);  

        String unicodeMsg = text.toString ; 

            msg.setUserData(unicodeMsg.getBytes("UTF-16BE"));
            msg.setCodingGroup(SmsMessage.DC_GROUP_GENERAL);      
            msg.setAlphabet(SmsMessage.DC_UCS2);              
            msg.setMessageClass(SmsMessage.NO_CLASS);             
            service.init(props);
            service.connect();
            service.sendMessage(msg);         
            System.out.println("Message sent successfuly,  "+msg.getMessage());       
              service.disconnect();
```

Comment: important is if sms_gate accepting those unicode chars, or encoding type

Comment: @mKorbel  in my first case, i.e on directly typing the text, it sends out perfectly and i get that script on my phone. But when i extract it from TextArea, it seems theres some problem

Comment: Did you check whether your database stores the text correctly?

Comment: @AaronDigulla When i display content in my GUI from my database, it displays all the unicode characters correctly.

Comment: Did you step through `SendUnicodeMessage` to make sure the message is encoded correctly? Does the last `System.out.println` work?

Comment: @AaronDigulla It is not displaying the characters in the console. `Select phone_no from users where region in ('Pune')
[+919561356345]
Iam in case 3
???? ??????? ??? ???? ?? ???? ?? ??????? ??. ????????? ????????? ?? ????? ???.
taMessage.getText()= ???? ??????? ??? ???? ?? ???? ?? ??????? ??. ????????? ????????? ?? ????? ???.`

Comment: Use a console that supports unicode and select a font which has the necessary characters. Or use a helper function to convert characters above code point 255 to hex codes so you can manually check a few of them to see whether they are correct.

Comment: This eclipse console does support unicode. Like in my first case, when i type the string in the code, it shows in my console `Message sent successfully, "ఈ ఒక తెలుగు సందేశం"`

Comment: @AaronDigulla I think, if i'am not wrong, the problem here is in getting the string correctly from the textArea. There is some problem with the encoding.

Comment: That's not possible because `JTextArea` uses the same string type as the rest of Java, so if you can read the text in there, `getText()` will return the correct data. Your problem is that you don't know what is going on because you can't see anything as long as you're using the wrong font in your IDE. Select one which doesn't display little squares for your text.

Comment: You can also try to step through the code in the debugger and look at the values of variables in the "Variables View". But again, use a font which supports the telugu script.

Comment: @AaronDigulla The font I'm using is Akshar Unicode, since it supports many Indian languages.  I downloaded the ttf file and used it in the code

Comment: You need to select it in Eclipse's preferences for the console and text editors so you can start to see what is going in the code.

Comment: okay... now somehow telugu is working. But other languages- hindi, tamil marathi - same problem

Answer (score 1):

You main problem is that computers can't magically paint characters on the screen. They not only need a font, they need a font which contains the characters you want to display. One clue for this problem is a small, empty rectangle instead of the character you need. If you see that, your font is useless.

So the first thing you have to do is to find a font that can display your text. Next, you need to install that font everywhere you need it. That also means to install it on your phone. Look up the instructions of your phone's OS to find out how to do that.

Do not confuse this problem with seeing `?`. The rectangle means "valid character but the font can't display it". The question mark in the output means that somewhere in the whole process, the en-/decoding got corrupted. This happens, for example, when you output UTF-8 on one side and read UTF-16 on the other side.